# Replace href with jQuery, regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, href

I have a bunch of href links that need to be replaced:

```
<a id="link" href="http://localhost:8091/tabid/99/catid/8/page1.aspx">Page1</a>
<a id="link" href="http://localhost:8091/tabid/98/catid/8/page1.aspx">Page1</a>
<a id="link" href="http://localhost:8091/tabid/97/catid/8/page1.aspx">Page1</a>
```

The href should be changed to:
"http://localhost:8091/tabid/**1**/catid/8/page1.aspx"

By searching I found:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#link").each(function () {
        this.href = this.href.replace("99", "1");
    });
});
```

This should do the job. However, it only replaces one of the links. Could anyone help me with the regular expression here? I need to change all the numbers in `tabid/**/catid` to "**1**".

Comment: you have multiple elements with the same id... this is not valid.  change your id's to classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change id to class. Second, make this change:

```
this.href = this.href.replace(/tabid\/\d+/i, '/tabid/1');
```

Now it only replaces the numbers after tabid, not just any number anywhere in the string.

Comment: Then by all means, +1 the answer so future viewers can know. And I get my +15 crack.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is using an `id` to access multiple elements: an `id`, [according to the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2), ***must be unique in the document***. Using an `id` causes JavaScript to return the first element it finds, rather than continuing searching through the document (since there ***must*** be only one).

To use the same name for multiple elements use a `class` instead:

```
<a class="link" href="http://localhost:8091/tabid/**99**/catid/8/page1.aspx">Page1</a>
<a class="link" href="http://localhost:8091/tabid/**98**/catid/8/page1.aspx">Page1</a>
<a class="link" href="http://localhost:8091/tabid/**97**/catid/8/page1.aspx">Page1</a>
```

With amended jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".link").each(function () {
        this.href = this.href.replace("99", "1");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element. In your case they are not unique. Try using css selectors or target all "a" elements.

Answer (score 0):

A id is unique in the document, you should use class instead.